# Setup HTTPS for tomcat 9 with load balancer

Tags: tomcat, https

I try to setup HTTPS for tomcat 9 behind F5 Load Balancer.
I have the certificate for the domain: A.domain.com, that domain point to F5 Load Balancer.
I import the certificate files to tomcat. Tomcat hostname is B.domain2.com
When I access the https link from F5, I see chrome throws a warning:
`This server could not prove that it is A.domain.com; its security certificate is from B.domain2.com...`

When I click to view certificate in Chrome, I still see the Issued to is: A.domain.com. And the Subject Alternative name is B.domain2.com

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I can make it work by adding more domain in Subject Alternative Name. This property now contains:
A.domain.com
B.domain2.com
Please see the detail here: https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm